# Object returning wrong Date format?

Tags: javascript, date

I get this string from a date propertie that is stored in a variable named

```
variables: 2020-12-09T15:12:46-03:00
```

Then I create a new Date:

```
const date = new Date(variables.date)
```

But when I try to access `date.hour` I get undefined
I also did `typeof date` and the result is `object`

Is the propertie returning a invalid date format? How can I fix this?

Comment: date objects don't have `hour` property  - read [documenttion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) - also, `typeof` returns limited information, so, yeah a `Date` is an `Object` - but `Object.prototype.toString.call(date)` will show `[object Date]` - you can also use `({}).toString.call(date)` for shorter code

Comment: there's also `Date.prototype.isPrototypeOf(date)` and `date instanceof Date` to test if `date` is a `Date`

Comment: @Bravo—both of which can fail over frames, `Object.prototype.toString.call(date)` is reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript the method to get the hours is getHours(). So you should use `date.getHours()` instead of `date.hour`

Answer (score 1):

in the `variables` you are not storing a valid string and as said you call `date.getHours()`:

```js
let dateObj = {
    variables: '2020-12-09T15:12:46-03:00'
}

const date = new Date(dateObj.variables)

console.log(date.getHours())
console.log(date.toDateString())
```